# Windows 10 upgrade infinite boot loop after failing to upgrade from 7

Tags: windows, windows-10-upgrade

Windows 10 infinite boot loop after failing to upgrade from 7.
Failed at around 30% and is trying to revert OS.
It's been infinite rebooting overnight now.
I assuming its trying to get back to 7.

Going through the same screens:
- Boot screen
- (Flickers through 2 different screens really fast, one is the the F8 screen)
- Windows is loading files...
- (spinny ball)
- (flashes what looks to be a cmd window)
- (microseconds of a mouse cursor)
- Attempting to recover installation...
- Restoring your previous version of Windows...
- (microseconds of a mouse cursor)
-> (Loops)

I can't F8 to get into safemode or other recovery options.
It bypasses my cd/dvd boot so I can't use a windows CD.
I can get into the BIOS but there isn't much there to help.

RIP laptop. Any ideas?

Comment: Restore from your last disk image? If you can get to BIOS, then  you should be able to boot from rescue media (e.g. WinPE or Linux) for the restore.

Comment: My laptop was stuck in a similar loop until I disconnected the extra mouse. Suggest you unplug everything but power if you haven't already, and good luck.

Comment: My BIOS is old so its very limited to what it can do. Right now it bypasses any bootable media, i've tried booting with the win7 disc (even removing the sata boot from the boot sequence) but the boot loop ignores it. Everything is unplugged, last resort would be to remove my hard drive and try to fix it remotely.

Comment: now im scared to upgrade my other machines :< thx microsoft-bama